# write .htaccess rewrite website URL multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I´m new to .htaccess and I am having problems in rewriting some URLs.

My website is made with php and has 2 parameters: param1 and param2.
The URLs look like similar to:

```
www.website.com/index.php?param1=12345678
www.website.com/index.php?param1=09876543

www.website.com/index.php?param2=abcdefgh
www.website.com/index.php?param2=qwertzui
```

I would like to create a .htaccess file to remove “index.php”, replace param1 and param2 with 2 names and add “.html” at the end, so they became:

```
www.website.com/budget/12345678.html
www.website.com/budget/09876543.html

www.website.com/user/abcdefgh.html
www.website.com/user/qwertzui.html
```

I have got this code (copied from internet).
It removes the .php extension but in the internally forward it rewrite it at the end of the URL neglecting the parameters.

Is someone so kind to help me to write the code?

Thanks :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# handle ?param1=...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?param1=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /budget/%1.html? [R=301,L,NE]

# handle ?param2=...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?param2=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1.html? [R=301,L,NE]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^budget/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?param1=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?param2=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```